React wont render basic server data- comes up as null
I just want to render server data on screen.
export async function authentication () {
    const [error, setError]= useState(null)
    const [recoveryCodes, setRecoveryCodes] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const router= useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    async function verify () { 
    try{
    const userId = searchParams.get('userId');
    const secret = searchParams.get('secret');
    await axios.get('/api/currentuser', {withCredentials : true})
    await axios.post('/api/verifyemail', {userId, secret})

    router.replace('/emailmfa') ; 
    }
    catch (error: any)
    {
     setError(error)

      alert(JSON.stringify(error))
      alert('Verification failed')}
    } ;


   //const recoverycodes= await fetch('/api/otp', {credentials : 'include'}).then(response => response.json() ).catch(error => setError(error))
   const fetchRecoveryCodes= async ()=>{
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/otp', { withCredentials: true });
      alert(response.data)
      setRecoveryCodes(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false)
    } catch (error: any) {
      
      alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data.detail));
      setError(error.response.data.detail); 
      setIsLoading(false)// Set a user-friendly error message
      // Reset recovery codes on error
    }} ;
   useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecoveryCodes()
     }, []);


    return (
        

        <div className=" flex h-screen w-screen justify-center items-center justify-items-center"> 
        <div className=" w-[400px]">
        <Card>
     <CardHeader>
     <CardTitle> Email OTP and verifcation</CardTitle>
      <CardDescription> These recovery codes can only be generated ONCE. Please save them in a secure place </CardDescription>
     </CardHeader>
     <CardContent>
     { isLoading? 'loading' : error ? 
             <p>{error}</p> 
            :  
            <p>{recoveryCodes} </p>
              //<p>{JSON.stringify(recoveryCodes)}</p> 
     }
     </CardContent>
     <CardFooter>
      
     </CardFooter>
     <div className=" flex p-4 justify-center">  
        <Button variant="outline" onClick={verify}>Verify me!</Button>
        </div>
   
     </Card>
     </div>
        </div>
     )



}

export default authentication ;

I want to render the server data in the page. It keeps coming up as null/empty. The alert in the use effect func shows that the data is there. Just won't render in the page because this framework is dog shit. I've tried as much chatgpt etc as i can. Just doesn't seem to be working

hi, can you please upload the full component code?  so that I can look into the issue properly

@MuhammadHassaan uploaded it

Did chatgpt suggest to use alerts for debugging?

I'm surprised you're not getting an error for exporting an async function as a component.    Have you tried to simplify the component to just updating state with some mock data?   Such as having the verify function just run setRecoveryCodes({name:"foo"}) and change the loading state to false?   Just get the basics of state setting and reading first, then try to make it work with real data.

Have you tried adding { headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"} }

@ScottZ yes tried that

@ScottZ the async in the component was the reason it wasn't working!
